# How do I create a new column with difference in date in r

Tags: r

My data Looks Like this

```
acc<-c(1:7)
openD<-c("2011-02-12","2015-03-12","2015-01-19","2014-08-12","2013-01-12","2015-01-01","2011-06-15")
Vdate<-c("2011-02-27","2015-04-28","2015-02-02","2015-08-11","2015-01-02","NA","2015-06-15")

datasm <- data.frame(acc,openD,Vdate)
```

I am trying to figure out how to create a new colume that will compare the openD to the Vdate.  essentially and if then statement:
IF - openD or Vdate is NA THEN "unknown" ELSE IF Open is in same month as Vdate THEN "InMonth" ELSE IF Open is in following month as Vdate "In Month +1" ELSE IF Open is within 1 year of Vdate "In 1 Year"  ELSE IF Open is within 2 years of Vdate "In 2 Years" ELSE "More than 2 years"

Resulting in something like this:

```
TimeDif<- c("InMonth","In Month +1", "In Month +1", "In 1 Year","In 2 Years", "Unknown", "More than 2 years")
datasre<- data.frame(acc,openD,Vdate,TimeDif)
```

i have looked all over and cant find anything that looks at dates this way.  New to r so bear with me

Comment: corrected the date sorry

Comment: I think all you want to do is convert the two columns to date with `as.Date` then since there are arithmetic methods for dates you can do `with(datasm, Vdate - openD)` and use those counts for your if statement

Comment: @RichardScriven The number of days generally won't translate to tests of having the same month or year. Prolly cleaner to load a package with  `month` and `year` accessor function, like data.table or lubridate.

Comment: the problem I am running into is that I dont want with 30 days I want in the same month

Comment: I can't figure out how to get a Month and Year format with any package.  I can get MDY or just MONTH or Just Year.  I know I have to be missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly beyond belief, but seems to work. Takes advantage of the internal formatting of `yearmon(...)` in the `zoo` package.

```
f <- function(x,y) {
  require(zoo)   # for as.yearmon(...)
  x <- as.numeric(as.yearmon(as.Date(x)))
  y <- as.numeric(as.yearmon(as.Date(y)))
  ifelse((is.na(x) | is.na(y)), "Unknown",
         ifelse(x==y, "InMonth", 
                ifelse(y-x<0.1, "Month+1", 
                       ifelse(y-x <= 1, "In 1 Year", 
                              ifelse(y-x<=2, "In 2 Years", "More Than 2 Years")))))
}
with(datasm, f(openD, Vdate))
# [1] "InMonth"           "Month+1"           "Month+1"           "In 1 Year"         "In 2 Years"        "Unknown"           "More Than 2 Years"
```

Slightly cleaner version:

```
f <- function(x,y) {
  require(zoo)   # for as.yearmon(...)
  x <- as.numeric(as.yearmon(as.Date(x)))
  y <- as.numeric(as.yearmon(as.Date(y)))
  ret.val <- c("InMonth","Month+1", "In 1 Year", "In 2 Years", "More Than 2 Years")
  brks    <- c(0, 0.08, 1, 2, Inf)
  ifelse((is.na(x) | is.na(y)), "Unknown", ret.val[cut(y-x, brks, labels=FALSE, right=FALSE)])
}
with(datasm, f(openD, Vdate))
# [1] "InMonth"    "Month+1"    "Month+1"    "In 1 Year"  "In 2 Years" "Unknown"    "In 2 Years"
```

Comment: @jihoward I get  : Error in f(openD, Vdate) : could not find function "as.yearmon"

Comment: Do you have the `zoo` package installed??

Comment: Ok I reran the install now I am getting:

Comment: Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: @jihoward I think the error I am getting is because of the NA in Vdate

Comment: Does it run with the example you provided? I'm using your code exactly.

Comment: Yes I am running fine with the example now.  I still can't get it to run on full data set.

Comment: It's possible that your `NA`s are `"NA"`s, which is different. Is `any(is.na(datasm$openD))` TRUE? What about `any(datasm$OpenD=="NA")`? Same for the other column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89319/discussion-between-ally-kat-and-jlhoward).

Comment: Thank you for all your help, this worrks except, this produces a function but does not create a new column like in the sample results in the question

Comment: `datasm$TimeDif <- with(datasm, f(openD, Vdate))`